# InfoWindow.getSelectedFeature() not working

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, events

When I select a geometry on map, the method `map.infoWindow.getSelectedFeature()` always returns `"undefined"`. It looks like it is not working.
This behavior is with `InfoWindow` and also with `Popup`.
Also not working event `map.infoWindow.on("selection-change",...`.

Code:

```
map = new Map("mapDiv", {});    
map.infoWindow.on("selection-change", function ()     
{    
   var graphic = map.infoWindow.getSelectedFeature();    
   // graphics is always "undefined"    
}
```

How to read currently selected feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html) is different than the infoWindow in its implementation.

> The Popup class is an implementation of InfoWindow that inherits from InfoWindowBase to provide additional capabilities.

and

> Popups provide the following additional capabilities:

```
  •Provides a user interface to navigate through multiple selections.
  •Zoom and highlight selected feature.
  •Maximize the info window.
```

The popup has events and methods that the infoWindow doesn't have, such as the "selection-change" and "getSelectedFeature". For example, in this [sample](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=find_popup), this code insertion returns the selected feature.

```
map.on("load", mapReady);

//new code
popup.on("selection-change", function(){
  var graphic = popup.getSelectedFeature();
  console.log(graphic);
});
//end of code

var parcelsURL = "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/BloomfieldHillsMichigan/Parcels/MapServer";
```

If you want to get the selected feature, why not listen to the map's click event or, if you're using a FeatureLayer, utilize its "[selection-complete](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#event-selection-complete)" event, which returns an array of graphics.